# Formatting grid's row in Kendo UI for Angular 2 grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am wondering if there is a way to format the row's appearance based on a field's value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little too late, but its possible!

> HTML

How to style based on row:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [rowClass]="rowCallback">
     <kendo-grid-column field="machineName" title="Machine">
     </kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="article" title="Article">
     </kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="status" title="Status">
     </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

How to style based on column:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [rowClass]="cellCallback">
     <kendo-grid-column field="machineName" title="Machine">
     </kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="article" title="Article">
     </kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="status" title="Status" [class]="{'yourCssClass':true}>
     </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Here, `status` can be `started` or `stopped`. So, let's say we want to style the row 
 conditionally based on that value.

> CSS

```
.green .stopCodeColor {background-color: #00c853 !important;}
.red .stopCodeColor {background-color: #d50000 !important;}
.yellow .stopCodeColor {background-color: #ffd600!important;}
/***** below are only used for ROW-styling ****/
.redRow {background-color: #d50000 !important;}
.greenRow {background-color: #00c853 !important;}
.yellowRow {background-color: #ffd600!important;}
```

> TS

```
private rowCallback = (context: RowClassArgs) => {
  switch (context.dataItem.status) {
      case "STOPPED":
          return "redRow";
      case "STARTED":
          return "greenRow";
      case "ERROR":
          return "yellowRow";
      default:
          return {};
  }
}
private cellCallback = (context: RowClassArgs) => {
  switch (context.dataItem.status) {
      case "STOPPED":
          return "red";
      case "STARTED":
          return "green";
      case "ERROR":
          return "yellow";
      default:
          return {};
  }
}
```

*Note:* `ViewEncapsulation.None` in order to make this work.

API: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/RowClassArgs/

## DEMO

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tylq1k?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @Joel.  Is there a reason for the ViewEncapsulation.None requirement?  I am concerned that this would interfere with the global css of the application.

Comment: @dpdragnev What you could do is to prefix the css-classes using the component-selector. Which would in this case be: `my-app .green .etc.etc.etc` then it wont bleed into your global css. If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Got,  I was just wondering why ViewEncapsulation.None is needed.

Comment: @dpdragnev Since we're using another module which we are trying to load styling into (our component => kendo). We need to set viewencapsulation to none. which means: No Shadow DOM at all. Therefore, also no style encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<kendo-grid>
    <kendo-grid-column>
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <!--Anything can go here-->
            <!--This is also per column, not per entry in the array-->
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**EDIT:**

Updated to newer template syntax

Comment: "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements, so the above code will NOT work anymore

Comment: @MihirKale when this was written, the syntax was "template", sometime after this was written, the syntax got changed to "ng-template". I have now updated the answer