# How to customize Angular 2 Kendo Grid rows and cells based on data item values

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am currently using Kendo UI Grid in Angular 2 and I have a requirement to apply background color to cells based on dataItem values. I tried doing it using Kendo Grid Column template (see code snippet below) but it does not fill the whole cell with that color (see screenshot attached). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also here is link to plunker example - http://plnkr.co/edit/hBXuPWO325XYYlDVehaI?p=preview.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3UU7.png)

```
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                <tbody class="{{dataItem.UnitPrice < 10 ? 'container-fluid bg-success' : 'container-fluid bg-warning'}}">{{dataItem.UnitPrice}}</tbody>
            </ng-template>  
        </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Could you please add the link to your Plunker-Editor instead of uploading an image. It could help others to reproduce the problem and fix it faster

Comment: Here is link to Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/hBXuPWO325XYYlDVehaI?p=preview

Comment: Any update, I am also facing same issue

Comment: @SaiKrishnaKuppa Please accept my answer if it did what you are asking for - as it might help other people in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, here I've modified your code to work.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    template: `
        <style>
           .green .cellStyle{background-color:#0f0;}
           .red .cellStyle{background-color:#f00;}
        </style>
        <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410" [rowClass]="rowCallback">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80" [class]="{'cellStyle':true}">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                    <div class="{{dataItem.UnitPrice < 10 ? 'm-0 p-0 bg-success' : 'm-0 p-0 bg-warning'}}">{{dataItem.UnitPrice}}</div>
                </ng-template>  
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="In stock" width="80">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" title="Discontinued" width="120">
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
                </ng-template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    private gridData: any[] = products;
    private rowCallback = (context: RowClassArgs) => {
       return context.dataItem.UnitPrice < 10 ? 'green' : 'red';  
      }
    }


}
```

Heres the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/h6OcGBL8AkzzpuAbcqYZ?p=preview

For a more elaborate answer, please check out my answer on this post for a demo too:

## MORE DEMOS

[Formatting grid's row in Kendo UI for Angular 2 grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842858/formatting-grids-row-in-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-grid/54787846#54787846)

Comment: This will not work if I need to style multiple columns based on their cell values

Comment: @MihirKale it does. The concept is the same. See the demo

Answer (score 1):

@Sai, @Parvez : Here is a possible solution to highlight the entire column for multiple columns.

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="Code" title="Code" width="30" class="no-padding">
          <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <span class="whole-cell" [style.backgroundColor]="colorCode(dataItem.IsDirtyCode)">
            {{dataItem.Code}}</span>
          </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

CSS:

```
    .k-grid .no-padding {
      padding: 0;
    }
     .whole-cell {
       display: block;
       padding: 11px 16px; /* depends on theme you need to increase the 
padding height and width so that it will cover the entire cell size rather than only a small part */
     }
```

TS:

```
public colorCode(item: boolean): SafeStyle {
    let result;

    switch (item) {
     case true :
       result = '#FFBA80';
       break;
     default:
       result = 'transparent';
       break;
    }

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(result);
  }
```

IMPORTANT:

1. Make `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the TS file at the component level so it won't breed out styles.
2. Add Import Statements:

   ```
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { RowClassArgs } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
   ```
3. Inject DomSanitizer:

   ```
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
   ```

Here is everything you need for multiple styling of cells. For more columns just add the ng-template in the column and call the colorCode() method passing the dataItem on which you want to make checks.

Refer this [article](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/styling/#toc-styling-cells-on-the-fly) for more information.

Hope it answers your issue !!