# How to change color of row based on particular column condition in kendo grid for angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-angular-ui

I want to apply red color to row whose completedIn hours column value is greater than 24. how can i do it. please help i am new to angular.

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData">
    <kendo-grid-column field="RequestNumber" title="Request No."  
width="110" >
    </kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="RequestNumber" title="Request No."  width="110" >
    </kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="Name" title="Name."  width="110" >
    </kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="CompletedIn" title="CompletedIn"  width="110" >
    </kendo-grid-column>
 </kendo-grid>
```

Comment: please help me guys

Comment: MORE DEMOS [Formatting grid's row in Kendo UI for Angular 2 grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842858/formatting-grids-row-in-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-grid/54787846#54787846)

Comment: Demo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842858/formatting-grids-row-in-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-grid/54787846#54787846

Answer (score 9):

First: you have to add `[rowClass]` to your grid

```
<kend-grid [rowClass]="rowCallback">
</kendo-grid>
```

then you need to add the function inside the component and return the needed class

```
public rowCallback(context: RowClassArgs) {
  if (context.dataItem.someProperty) {   // change this condition as you need
    return {
      passive: true
    };
  }
}
```

and last you need to have a CSS class with the name you returned,(in this case `passive` but of course you can change it as you want)

```
@Component({
  selector: "your-component",
  templateUrl: "./your.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [
    `
     .k-grid tr.passive {
        background-color: lightgray;
      }

    `
  ]
})
```

**it is very important** to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and name the class with the prefix `.k-grid tr` otherwise you will not get the needed result

Answer (score 2):

Use the **rowClass** callback to provide a custom class to all rows whose data items meet some custom criteria, then style them via CSS, e.g.:

[DOCS + DEMO](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-rowclass)

Answer (score -1):

This will mark the rows with red background color if the above condition is met

```html
<tr *ngFor="let myObject of myArray;" [ngStyle]="{'background-color':myObj.completedIn>24 ? 'red' : '' }">
   <!-- your other code -->
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.actually i am using kendo grid so don't have the <tr> tag